# Deserializing a BinaryFormatter result into another type

Tags: c#

We had recently rewritten our system's architecture and ran into a pretty big issue the day we went live.

We save a user's information as they are filling out their forms by serializing the form's model using BinaryFormatter and storing the result in the database:

```
private byte[] Serialize<T>(T model)
{
    try
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, model);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        _log.LogException(ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

When the user needed the information again, we would simply deserialize back into the same type and that worked great:

```
public  T Deserialize<T>(byte[] serializedData)
{
    try
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(serializedData))
        {
            var result = (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        _log.LogException(ex);
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

The problem comes in after the architecture rewrite and we had 3 clients that still had legacy form data saved.  The updated architecture's form models has the same property names but obviously new namespaces in a new assembly.

As a result the formatter.Deserialize is failing because it's trying to deserialize into an object that is in an assembly that is not in the new architecture.

Is there any possible way I can somehow deserialize into a generic object and then do a deep copy into the new model (or use automapper or something like that)? Or is the BinaryFormatter tightly tied to object and I would need the dll that contained the type definition that was used to do the serialization in order to do the deserialization?

Comment: The last one *the BinaryFormatter is tightly tied to the assembly-class-culture* which serialized it.  Look around and you can find a way to "trick" it by using a custom SerializationBinder.  There is a 3rd Party faster serializer which doesnt have that problem

Comment: @Plutonix SerializationBinder seems to be exactly what I am looking for.  I need to work out how to distinguish between multiple versions of the same namespace in different assemblies and also different namespaces in the same assembly but I think this is what I'll need to get it to work. If you have any more information I would really appreciate it. In any case, if you provide your response as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: A SerializationBinder just propagates the problem endlessly into the future as new versions and such emerge.  ProtoBuf-NET is a data contract binary serializer which is free of such constraints.  A SerializationBinder could play a role in deserializing legacy data then PBN for everything going forward.